# Sequence and convergence with subsequence

Tags: general-topology

Prove:$x_{n}\rightarrow x \implies x_{n_{i}} \rightarrow x$ for any subsequence.

Normally I would have a proof of this at least attempted proof, but I am really confused what my professor is trying to ask me to do here, hes an old Irishman and he tends to make mistakes or be a little lazy in writing out homework questions. I really just need this statement to be explained in words. I apologize for not providing a proof but I just dont understand the notation nor would it be possible to contact my professor which I would have done and have avoided posting this all together

Comment: "Prove that if the sequence $\{x_n\}$ converges to $x$, then every subsequence of $\{x_n\}$ converges to $x$ as well".  Is that clear enough?

Comment: Yea that works thank you

Comment: Do you know the limit infimum and limit supremum?

Comment: no haven't gone over that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the definition of convergence.  For every $\epsilon > 0$, there is an $N \in \Bbb N$ such that $n > N \implies \|x_n - x\| < \epsilon$.

We need to use this show that for every such $\epsilon$, we can find an $I \in \Bbb N$ such that $i > I \implies \|x_{n_i} - x\| < \epsilon$.  Use the definition of a subsequence in order to do so.